# Cell phone puzzle

Tags: word, english

When I write text messages on my mobile phone I just need to press each key
once for each letter and it automatically finds the most likely word that
fits the combination (abc=2, def=3, ghi=4, jkl=5, mno=6, pqrs=7, tuv=8,
wxyz=9). So if I press 84373 it displays *"there"*, although the word could
as well be *"these"*.

What is the longest pair of English words that have the same number combination, while having no common letter in the same position?

Note: The words must occur in the Merriam Webster dictionary; only uncapitalized words; no hyphens.

Comment: Can you define "common letter"?

Comment: "brushed" and "astride" seem good, but I have no idea if they're optimal.

Comment: Seems like programmers will defeat puzzlers again :(

Comment: @Gamow You're right about "open-ended", sorry! I was thinking this was much like the other "open-ended" puzzles involving "find the longest dictionary word such that...", but this one is different because it specifies a (searchable) dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

> 278-7433: astride and brushed 
>  266-8687: amounts and contour 
>  468-2337: hotbeds and invader

These seem to be the longest pairs that don't share a letter in the same place.
If you allow letters in the same place, there is a 10-letter pair, including area code:

> (732)773-7833: rearrested and reasserted.

These seem to be the longest pairs, and it's a coincidence it's the same length as a phone number.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> **8**. <strike>Two pairs achieve this length: **jingling** and **khoikhoi** translated as **54645464**, as well as</strike> **acacetin** and **cacafugo** translated as **22223846**

Why?

> Brute-forced on a dictionary.

Comment: But "Khoikhoi" is capitalized.

Comment: @Martin So? I don't see this mentioned anywhere in the problem statement...

Comment: the stetement reads "only uncapitalized words"

Comment: @Martin I did not notice that. Either way, the other pair is correct, so I see no reason for downvotes.

Comment: "cacafugo" is not in Merriam Webster, but "cacafuego" is.